# There is no open street map in my user preferences

Tags: import, blender-osm

I opened user preferences and clicked on add ons and then typed openstreet map but there is no open street map showing in he settings.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it is not part of the standard addons packaged with Blender. You can always install new addons by clicking "Install from file" and selecting the zip or py file containing the addon. In your case the blender-osm addon.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the blender-osm addon for free [here](https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm). Then use a normal addon installation as pointed in the other answer.